# selenium webdriver word count from page source

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

how to get edit id count 
i have tried as below[pagesource code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FlOF.png)
string[] rowcount=driver.getPageSource().split("a

Answer (score 3):

The ideal method is the one suggested by Buaban, you should ideally use         **findElements** for such purposes using the element attributes:

`int rowcount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\a[contains(@id,'edit')]")).size();`

But if still you want to go via **getPageSource**(), it's going to be a bit tricky. Since, you would be getting a string now without much distinction between elements and their attributes. You'll have to use some core java concepts here:

```
String str = driver.getPageSource();
String findStr = "id=\"edit";
int rowcount = str.split(findStr, -1).length-1;
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: thanks prateek . it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can find the elements that id contains 'edit' then count the results. See code below:
`int rowcount = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id*='edit']")).size();`